# AngularJS: Variables "Global" to a Service

Tags: angularjs

I am still working on my first AngularJS project (learning a lot as I go by mimicking an existing app) and wos wondering about best practices and better techniques.

I have a service which pulls form data to a SharePoint 365 list. By mimicking the example I am able to grab data from any list. The concern I have is the duplication of code. Every function declares the SAME local variables and all I do is change the function name and query but there is a LOT of duplicity. Ultimately I will be pulling from over 30 lists and will have to keep duplicating crap until I learn this correctly.

For example, here are two of the "shorter" functions.

```
appITI.service('SharePointJSOMService', function($q, $http){
// GET PRIORITIES
    this.getPriorities = function(){
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
        hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
        appweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPAppWebUrl"]);

        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor.executeAsync({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/GetByTitle('itipriorities')/items?$select=id,Title&@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
            deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(data.body));
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            deferred.reject(JSON.stringify(xhr));
        }
    });
    return deferred;
}; // /getPriorities

// GET PRIORITYGROUPS
this.getPriorityGroups = function(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
    appweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString["SPAppWebUrl"]);

    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/GetByTitle('itiPriorities')/items?$select=id,Priority_Group&@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
            deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(data.body));
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            deferred.reject(JSON.stringify(xhr));
        }
    });
        return deferred;
    }; // /getPriorities
}
```

I don't know enough about AngularJS and promises to know what I can change and what I can't but I am learning. I don't want to learn it the wrong way.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Have you looked into `$resource`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: LOL ... I have now. So, if I read the page correctly, all the "non-changing" stuff stays in the resource and I just pass it the query URL and work with the return?

Comment: Yeah. Just a note, $resource requests don't directly return promises like `$http` does. Instead it returns an object with $promise as an item on the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a single method to reduce your codebase. And closures with metadata to simplify creating your service. This could look like:

```
appITI.factory('SharePointJSONService', function($q, $http,metadata){
    var service = {};
    angular.forEach(metadata,function(listDescriptor,listName){
        //this === service
        this["get"+listName] = function(){ return get(listDescriptor); }; 
    },service);

    function get(listDescriptor){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
        hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString[listDescriptor.hostUrl]);
        appweburl = decodeURIComponent(JSRequest.QueryString[listDescriptor.appUrl]);
        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor.executeAsync({
            url: appweburl + listDescriptor.path; 
            method: listDescriptor.method,
            headers: listDescriptor.headers
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
                deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(data.body));
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                deferred.reject(JSON.stringify(xhr));
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }        
    return service;
});
```

You will just need to create a metadata object such that it will satisfy that code. Something like:

```
appITI.constant('metadata',{
    Priorities: {
        hostUrl: ...
        appUrl: ...
        method: "GET",
        headers: ...
        etc..
    },
    PriorityGroups:{
       ...
    }

});
```

You then use the angular promise from `$q` so there is no need for a `$scope.$apply`
In your controller:

```
SharePointJSONService.getPriorities().then(
    function success(res){ 
        $scope.priorities = res.d.results;
    },
    function error(){ //error });
```

Comment: and that metadata object would be in the controller? currently I call the things like `$.when(SharePointJSOMService.getPriorities())
    .done(function(jsonObject){
     $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.priorities = jsonObject.d.results;
     });
    })
    .fail(function(err){
     console.info(JSON.stringify(err)); 
    });~

Comment: it would be an `appITI.constant` or `appITI.value`

Comment: AWESOME! I just saw your updated example. One last question ( I hope ) ... since the appweburl and hostweburl are always the same, do I have to include those in the .constant or can I establish that in the factory function get

Comment: Sure! they can be left out, Whatever makes sense for your configuration

Comment: I was looking for how to set deferred.resolve(data); with the data, tks